# The best way for authentication Silverlight client with WCF service

Tags: silverlight, wcf, security

I have Silverlight application. It has to communicate with server over WCF services. It also needs some way to perform authentication of client.

When I developed windows forms application, I used WSHttpBinding and message security. I could to provide username and password and validate it at server.

But now I found that Silverlight does not support WSHttpBinding and does not support any kind of message security.

So what is the best way to provide user credentials to WCF service from Silverlighth application? What bindings should I use and how to secure communication between client and server?

Comment: It might not support message security, but have you looked at transport security?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simplest is the use Basic Http Binding with SSL transport encryption.

This has the same effect as using HTTPS between a browser and a web server, it will encrypt all transport between the client and the web server.

Comment: But will it transfer user name and password to the server?